# Negative degrees of freedom in multilevel SEM

Tags: interpretation, degrees-of-freedom, lavaan

Can someone please help me understand why I have negative amount of degrees of freedom in my output? I am doing a multilevel sem in lavaan and have 1 level 2 variable and 3 level 1 variables[image: conceptualised model] Thanks!

> ```
> lavaan 0.6-3 ended normally after 4380 iterations
>
> Optimization method                               EM
> Number of free parameters                         24
>
>                                                 Used       Total
> Number of observations                           151         157
> Number of clusters [team]                         38
>
> Estimator                                         ML      Robust
> Model Fit Test Statistic                          NA          NA
> Degrees of freedom                                -3          -3
> Scaling correction factor                           
> for the Yuan-Bentler correction (Mplus variant)
>
> Parameter Estimates:
>
> Information                                 Observed
> Observed information based on                Hessian
> Standard Errors                   Robust.huber.white
> ```
>
> UPDATE
>
> here is the input, which will hopefully give you a better insight into what I am doing. Thanks!
>
> ```
> #calculate level 2 model with coach FF as explanatory variable
>
>
> mlm <- 'level: within
>         athlete_ff ~wc*ccb + wb*pnts
>         pnts ~ wa*ccb
>
>    level: between
>         ccb~coach_ff
>         athlete_ff ~ bc*ccb + bb*pnts
>         pnts ~ ba*ccb
>
> #correlation
>
> athlete_ff~~pnts
> athlete_ff~~ccb
> pnts~~ccb
> ccb~~coach_ff
>
> #defined parameters
> wi := wa * wb
> bi := ba * bb
> '
> fit4 <- sem(mlm, data = Rdata_complete, cluster = "team",optim.method= "em", estimator= "MLR", std.lv=TRUE)
> summary(fit4)
> ```

Comment: Questions about Lavaan specifically are off topic on cross validated so I edited the question.. You have negative df because you have two many parameters. We can't tell what, without seeing the input and knowing more about the data, but my guess is that you don't have enough teams.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thanks for your reply! I have edited my original post and added the input as well, I hope this helps a bit. I made some changes to the correlations, and now I have been able to reduce the number to -1df, however, that's probably still not ideal. By having negative df, does that mean I am unable to interpret anything from my results, or am I being overly concerned?

Comment: Yes, if you have negative DF you cannot interpret anything.

Comment: ok thanks for this, do you have any recommendations on what the next step would be to deal with it, other than have more teams?

Comment: No ideas, except more teams. Or a different approach.